# How does android implement the app for background tcp alerts

Tags: java, android, networking, tcp

I would like to program an APP that can be resident in the background and connected to the server to trigger a vibrator alarm when a specified message is received. In other platforms just open a thread, using http or TCP implementation is very simple.  but the android will always be killed by memory management, but there is no good idea to solve the problem of being killed by memory management.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that thing by using Receiver and Services in Android.

Search on Google for how you can implement Receiver and Service for your purpose.

Service always runs in background.
Receiver is called when any function is triggered (e.g. sms/call received).